# flex actionscript LatLngBounds can not get it to work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, google-maps-api-3, bounds

My question is at the very end of the post.

I have tried everything from setting a timer for all the markers to be set to all kinds of calculations of the four corners, but nothing seems to be working.

Each time that I add a marker to the markermanager, I call this function below

```
public function markerSetBounds(someLat , someLng):void{
    var bounds:LatLngBounds = new LatLngBounds();

    for(var i:int = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++)
{
    var currentLatLon:LatLng = new LatLng(someLat , someLng);
        bounds.extend(currentLatLon);
}

googleMap.setZoom(googleMap.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
googleMap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
}
```

I believe I know why this does not work. I am only sending one set of lat, lng at a time.

However, when I tried the following, flex told me that it did not know what `myMarkers[i].lat` meant.

The following is how I fill myMarkers array

```
var someMarker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(someLat , someLng), new MarkerOptions({tooltip:someAddress, hasShadow: true}));
myMarkers.push(someMarker);
```

This is how I want to traverse through the array, but flex does not understand what .lat means.

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++)
{
    var currentLatLon:LatLng = new LatLng(myMarkers[i].lat , myMarkers[i].lng);
    bounds.extend(currentLatLon);
}
```

My question is how do I traverse through the myMarkers array to set currentLatLon. I have also tried a `for each(var someObj:Marker in myMarkers)` but it finds nothing. The markers are showing up on the map, but the bounds are not working.

Comment: This is perfectly valid code. The default items in an array are of the `Object` type, so `myMarkers[i].lat` should compile. If it gives you an error at run-time, then that means you haven't set `myMarkers[i].lat`. Debug through your code and see if that;s really what you should be referencing

Comment: Thank you Pranav. I was able to do the following - for each(someMarker in myMarkers){ var newLatLng:LatLng = someMarker.getLatLng(); Alert.show(newLatLng.toString()); bounds.extend(newLatLng);} However, it is still not extending the bounds to show the new markers that have been added

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing something like:

```
(myMarkers[i] as Marker).lat
```

Is this a problem at run time or compile time?

Comment: Gordon, welcome to stackOverflow. I suggest you read the [faq]. You'll see that if you want to ask if they have tried something, or if you want more details, such posts go in the "Comments" section, and you do not post them as an answer. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for asking Gordon. When I tried for each(var someObj:Marker in myMarkers) during debug, then no errors come up, but at the same time, it does not set the bounds. As if there were no someObj found.

Comment: Have you tried a regular for loop? eg `for(var i:int = 0; i < myMarkers.length; ++i)` I've had problems in the past with for-each-in loops not being entered (as if there were no objects in an array when I know that there are).

Comment: I was able to verify that the correct lat and lng are being used by doing this - for each(someMarker in myMarkers){ var newLatLng:LatLng = someMarker.getLatLng(); Alert.show(newLatLng.toString()); bounds.extend(newLatLng);} However, I am still not having the markers LatLngBounds set properly. In my init(), geocoder.geocode(textInput.text); where textInput has a value of Los Angeles, CA and that is where the map.center stays on, no matter how many markers are added. The user has to manually zoom out to view the markers.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out was what the issue and it was that I had to place things in the correct order.

First, declare the LatLngBounds.

Second, make the markers.

Third, set the zoom

Forth, extend the bounds.

```
                bounds = new LatLngBounds();

            covToXML = new XML(event.result);
            xmlToList = new XMLList(covToXML);
            listToCol = new XMLListCollection(xmlToList);
            someLat = Number(listToCol.children().child("geometry").child("location").child("lat").text());
            someLng = Number(listToCol.children().child("geometry").child("location").child("lng").text());
            someAddress = String(listToCol.children().child("formatted_address").text());

            var markerOptions:MarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            markerOptions.icon = new (whichIcon(GlobalVars.randomIcon));
            markerOptions.tooltip = someAddress;
            markerOptions.hasShadow = true;

            someMarker = new Marker(new LatLng(someLat , someLng), markerOptions);
            someMarker.addEventListener(MapMouseEvent.CLICK,markerClicked);

            myMarkers.push(someMarker);
            googleMap.addOverlay(someMarker);

            for each(someMarker in myMarkers)
            {
                var newLatLng:LatLng = someMarker.getLatLng();
                // Alert.show(newLatLng.toString());
                bounds.extend(newLatLng);
            }

            googleMap.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
            googleMap.setZoom(googleMap.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```

Thanks for all the suggestions and questions, which helped me to the solution.